# Time Series is not white noise but Random Walk

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive, moving-average

I have time series data which is as shown below

[image]

To proceed with this series for building forecasting , I read many places if your data is not white noise and does not have random walk then you can model forecasting , Otherwise if your time series data is either white noise or has random walk then don't use time series forecasting

Is above condition has any implication if it is white series or has random walk?

However , when I check my time series it has not white noise but has random walk

For white noise I checked it using ACF plot

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(df.Frequencylags = 50, ax= ax1)
```

[image]

White noise distributions have approximately 0 autocorrelation at all lags. Above ACF plot does not show any 0 autocorrelation hence time series is not white noise

When I check random walk by using 1 differencing and check its ACF plot then no learnable patterns are found in first order differencing. In short, don’t even bother with forecasting.

```
walk_diff = df['Frequency'].diff()

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(walk_diff.dropna(),lags = 40, ax= ax1)
```

[image]

When I do second order differencing then I see lag 1 in ACF plot shows learnable patterns in data once the series is stationary.Is my understanding correct after second order differencing ,ACF plot shows that data is not random walk. So with second order differencing I can go and use forecasting modelling?

```
walk_diff = data_dailies['Frequency'].diff().diff()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(walk_diff.dropna(),lags = 40, ax= ax1)
```

[image]

My question

1. What an implication on forecasting modelling if your data is not white noise but has random walk by first order difference?
2. What an implication on forecasting modelling if your data is not white noise and neither has random walk by second order differencing?

Having with this above confusion when I model using SARMIAX and train it first 0 to 233 days and forecast on 234 to 281 then model give me almost same sum of counts as we have in actual data

```
model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df_train['Frequency'],order=(1, 2, 0),seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1,44),dynamic = False)
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())
```

Upon forecasting

```
df_test['forecast'] = 0
df_test['forecast'] = model_fit.predict(df_test.index.min(),df_test.index.max(),dynamic=False)

df_test[['Frequency','forecast']].plot(figsize=(12,8));
```

[image]

```
print(f'Actual Count {df_test.Frequency.sum()} Vs Predicted Count {df_test.forecast.sum()}')

Actual Count 19471 Vs Predicted Count 20968.694112941106
```

Comment: you have to give us better axis titles or else I have no idea what I'm reading.

Comment: By eyeballing your data, it seems much more useful to consider seasonality when building a forecasting model. It does look neither white noise nor unit root nonstationary.

Comment: @Germania I changed axis labels of my data in first plot , please let me know if you want more information

Comment: Why are you differencing your data then drawing acf plots? You report the acf plots on the undifferenced data first.

Comment: @Germania first plot acf is for white noise using actual count , second acf plot using differenced random walk values to see after removing randomness in data by differencing to check whether data still white noise or not. I got this understanding from here https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-from-scratch-white-noise-and-random-walk-5c96270514d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To proceed with this series for building forecasting , I read many places if your data is not white noise and does not have random walk then you can model forecasting , Otherwise if your time series data is either white noise or has random walk then don't use time series forecasting

You can use ARIMA when you have a random-walk. If you have white noise data you can fit a OLS regression rather than ARIMA.

Comment: it means my data is random walk so I can go with ARIMA or SARIMAX?

Comment: Did you mean unit root instead of random walk? As RW is just what it is, there is no use of ARIMA modelling of it.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't have full understanding of unit root yet. However, I am here referring random walk. Now reading your response there is contradiction between you and Gerrmania. Now I am confused

Comment: @user172500, yes, these things may take time to understand...

Comment: @RichardHardy one thing is your statement about RW and this article are on same page, i believe random walk series is not good candidate for time series forecasting  https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-from-scratch-white-noise-and-random-walk-5c96270514d3

Comment: @RichardHardy can we use AR for above time series? Using AR with lag 50 model forecasting out of sample is very close to actual data

Comment: @user172500, I am sorry I cannot help you more; I am busy at work.